# Swapping a limit and a $\sup$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, banach-spaces

In [this proof](http://books.google.ch/books?id=oOYQVeHmNk4C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=hunter+proof+that+C%28K%29+is+complete&source=bl&ots=XKjSOj1KO8&sig=XTqYcIu7-dlwGAu5kmIwSmE-SNM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6kXwTrj4CoP44QTf-JWnAQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the completeness of $(C(K), \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ they use the following inequality:

$$ \sup_{x \in K} \lim_{m \to \infty} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \leq \liminf_{m \to \infty}\, \sup_{x \in K} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) |.$$

Can someone explain to me why this is true? Presumably, they first write $$ \sup_{x \in K} \lim_{m \to \infty} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | = \sup_{x \in K} \,\liminf_{m \to \infty} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) |$$ and then swap but the exact argument why this gives the inequality is unclear to me.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have for all $x\in K$, $m,n$ integers: $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in K}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ and taking the $\liminf$:
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\forall x\in K\quad\liminf_m|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\liminf_m\,\sup_{z\in K}|f_n(z)-f_m(z)|,$$
and now taking the supremum over $x\in K$ we get 
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N: \quad\sup_{x\in K}\,\liminf_m|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\liminf_m\,\sup_{z\in K}|f_n(z)-f_m(z)|,$$
hence 
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N: \quad\sup_{x\in K}\,\lim_m|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\liminf_m\,\sup_{z\in K}|f_n(z)-f_m(z)|,$$
since we've got the convergence of $\{f_n(x)-f_n(x)\}_m$.